# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to replace object: Service "api" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

When doing `helm upgrade ... --force` I'm getting this below error

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to replace object: Service "api" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
```

And This is how my service file looks like: (Not passing clusterIP anywhere )

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}-service
    kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Chart.Name | quote }}
    dns: route53
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 443
    name: https
    targetPort: http-port
    protocol: TCP
```

**Helm** Version: **3.0.1**

**Kubectl** Version: **1.13.1** [Tried with the **1.17.1** as well]

**Server**: **1.14**

**Note**: Previously I was using some old version (of server, kubectl, helm) at that time I did not face this kind of issue. 
I can see lots of similar issues in GitHub regarding this, but unable to find any working solution for me.

few of the similar issues:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25241

https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/13646 [For Nginx chart]

Comment: As you saw from [a comment on that issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/13646#issuecomment-561292933), the work-around seems to be to manually provide the existing `ClusterIP` value from your existing install -- that is, I understand you are not _currently_ passing the clusterIP, but you will need to add in an option that _will_ allow for providing it so that you can specify one until this catastrophe blows over

Comment: @mdaniel that workaround I saw, but I'm finding some more concrete fix, I kept that workaround as 2nd option as of now.

Comment: Have you tried to use `--set controller.service.omitClusterIP=true --set defaultBackend.service.omitClusterIP=true` as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6378) thread?

Comment: yes, but anyway, I don't have this `controller.service.omitClusterIP` anywhere in my custom chart.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've made some tests with Helm and got the same issue when trying to change the Service type from `NodePort/ClusterIP` to `LoadBalancer`.

This is how I've reproduced your issue:

**Kubernetes** 1.15.3 (GKE)
**Helm** 3.1.1

Helm chart used for test: [stable/nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress)

#### How I reproduced:

1. Get and decompress the file:

```
helm fetch stable/nginx-ingress  
tar xzvf nginx-ingress-1.33.0.tgz
```

2. Modify service type from `type: LoadBalancer` to `type: NodePort` in the `values.yaml` file (line 271):

```
sed -i '271s/LoadBalancer/NodePort/' values.yaml
```

3. Install the chart:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ./
```

4. Check service type, must be `NodePort`:

```
kubectl get svc -l app=nginx-ingress,component=controller

NAME                       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nginx-ingress-controller   NodePort   10.0.3.137   <none>        80:30117/TCP,443:30003/TCP   1m
```

5. Now modify the Service type again to `LoadBalancer` in the `values.yaml`:

```
sed -i '271s/NodePort/LoadBalancer/' values.yaml
```

6. Finally, try to upgrade the chart using `--force` flag:

```
helm upgrade nginx-ingress ./ --force
```

And then:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to replace object: Service "nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
```

#### Explanation

Digging around I found this in HELM [source code:](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/6bed5949cbff923851aac168373c5279f659c46a/pkg/kube/client.go#L428)

```golang
// if --force is applied, attempt to replace the existing resource with the new object.
    if force {
        obj, err = helper.Replace(target.Namespace, target.Name, true, target.Object)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to replace object")
        }
        c.Log("Replaced %q with kind %s for kind %s\n", target.Name, currentObj.GetObjectKind().GroupVersionKind().Kind, kind)
    } else {
        // send patch to server
        obj, err = helper.Patch(target.Namespace, target.Name, patchType, patch, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return errors.Wrapf(err, "cannot patch %q with kind %s", target.Name, kind)
        }
    }
```

Analyzing the code above Helm will use similar to `kubectl replace` api request (instead of `kubectl replace --force` as we could expect)... when the helm `--force` flag is set.

If not, then Helm will use `kubectl patch` api request to make the upgrade.

Let's check if it make sense:

#### PoC using kubectl

1. Create a simple service as `NodePort`:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   app: test-svc
 name: test-svc
spec:
 selector:
   app: test-app
 ports:
 - port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
 type: NodePort
EOF
```

Make the service was created:

```
kubectl get svc -l app=test-svc

NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
test-svc   NodePort   10.0.7.37    <none>        80:31523/TCP   25
```

Now lets try to use `kubectl replace` to upgrade the service to `LoadBalancer`, like `helm upgrade --force`:

```
kubectl replace -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 labels:
   app: test-svc
 name: test-svc
spec:
 selector:
   app: test-app
 ports:
 - port: 80
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 80
 type: LoadBalancer
EOF
```

This shows the error:

```
The Service "test-svc" is invalid: spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable
```

Now, lets use `kubectl patch` to change the NodePort to LoadBalancer, simulating the helm upgrade command *without* `--force` flag:

*[Here](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/) is the kubectl patch documentation, if want to see how to use.*

```
kubectl patch svc test-svc -p '{"spec":{"type":"LoadBalancer"}}'
```

Then you see:
`service/test-svc patched`

#### Workaround

You should to use `helm upgrade` without `--force`, it will work.

If you really need to use `--force` to recreate some resources, like pods to get the latest `configMap` update, for example, then I suggest you first manually change the service specs before Helm upgrade.

If you are trying to change the service type you could do it exporting the service `yaml`, changing the type and apply it again (because I experienced this behavior only when I tried to apply the same template from the first time):

```
kubectl get svc test-svc -o yaml | sed 's/NodePort/LoadBalancer/g' | kubectl replace --force -f -
```

The Output:

```
service "test-svc" deleted
service/test-svc replaced
```

Now, if you try to use `helm upgrade --force` and doesn't have any change to do in the service, it will work and will recreate your pods and others resources.

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Btw you dont need --force to recreate pods.  

Helm has a special flag for this: --recreate-pods.